# Gradle execution failed for task ‘:test’ when changing sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility from 1.8 to 13

Tags: gradle, java-8, gradlew, java-13

Following error occurs when migrating from source and target compatibility from 1.8 to 13
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ‘:test’.
Failed to read class file C:\Users\FixedSizeFifoDoubleArrayTest.class

Tried changing 
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code

```
tasks.withType(Test){
scanForTestClasses = false
include "**/*Test.class"
 }
```

to build.gradle file as described in the below link

[Execution failed for task ‘:test’ when changing sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility from 1.8 to 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58547958/execution-failed-for-task-test-when-changing-sourcecompatibility-and-targetco)